# Block Puzzle solving C++ algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, dynamic, backtracking

I want to make an algorithm for solving [Block Puzzles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.mtoy.blockpuzzle&hl=ro), but as efficient as possible. I already did the easy- way (a backtracking).

I represented everything as matrices- the big matrix the pieces have to fit is all on 0, at the beginning and the pieces are matrices with 1 if the space is full or 0 if space is empty.
Now the next possible more efficient idea is to always verify if a line is complete before going to the next one. What i mean is that I might have a piece represented as
`0 1 0

 1 1 1

 0 1 0`
(a cross). If the cross is put in a corner, the program will uselessly do the whole backtracking for an invalid solution, so it should go back and try another piece.

I can provide a piece of code if necessarily, as I said, I did  only the simple inefficient backtracking.
Does anyone has better ideas?   Can dynamic programming be used in this case?

Comment: Maybe, when a piece is placed, you count the number of zeros connected to any zeros in the placed piece, and if that number is less than the number of 1s in the smallest unplaced piece, then you know the placed piece is wrong?

Comment: Give me more details please. what is the max sizes, ..limits?

Comment: Not a real problem, just wanted to try it. Let's say the limit is an matrix of [INT_MAX/2][INT_MAX/2] so the maximum number of pieces is INT_MAX. Not relevant to the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the problem as a graph: the nodes are the various states in which the blocks can be arranged, and the edges are the possible moves from one node to another. Then the solution is the shortest distance from the current position to the target, which can be computed using Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: I have just started learning graph theory and I am currently reading Dijkstra's algorithm, but I find it a little hard to understand exactly what do you mean. I understand that the graph would contain the pieces as they are read. But how do I find out when the target is reached and how do I represent everything so I can put pieces in the container?

Comment: You already have a representation for the nodes, from your first solution. The graph is represented as adjacency lists: from each node, here are all the nodes that can be reached by a single move. The target is the desired final node. In some cases, including yours, there may be more than one possible target, so instead of Dijkstra's algorithm you may want a single-source shortest-paths algorithm (there are several); you probably want an algorithm that uses breadth-first search, so you can quit as soon as any target is reached.